# html tabs removeClass & addClass in jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an index page with tabs for now, they are not linking to anywhere yet but I'm trying to set the active class when you click on a tab.

Here are the tabs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            @foreach(var division in Model)
            {
                <li class="span2""><a href="#">@division.Description</a></li>
            }
            <li class="active span2"><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li class="span2"><a href="#">Summary</a></li>
        </ul>
```

And the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#tabs li").click(function() {
        $("#tabs li").removeClass('active'); 
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        $(selected_tab).fadeIn();
        var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    });
});
```

I also tried setting an onclick event on the tabs pointing to function SetActiveTab() and just trying to delete the active class in it but that also doesn't work:

```
function SetActiveTab() {
    $("#tabs li").removeClass("active");
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You have an error within your `foreach`, it should be `<li class="span2">`, with single quote `"`

Comment: just a typo, it is ok in my code. Must have slipped my finger while making this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to reference parent element of `li` by id `#tabs`. May be your code snippet is incomplete and you do have parent `#tabs` element for `li` but if not you can access `li` with class `.nav`, `.nav-tabs` or both `.nav.nav-tabs`. Also, this way you will access all set of tabs on your page, not only the one with specific id.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".nav.nav-tabs li").click(function() {
        $("#tabs li").removeClass('active'); 
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        $(selected_tab).fadeIn();
        var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you can specify an id for parent element of `li`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
```

Answer (score -1):

all of your code is referencing #tabs but your "ul" doesnt have an id of "tabs".

Comment: This is more of a comment (although valid, and correct). You need to provide some sort of solution, like keaukraine

Comment: lol thx that is it.. I looked over it a dozen times... sry for the post

Comment: Ian, good to know. I'll try to give more thorough answers. It's just that this one was pretty simple.

Comment: @AlbertVo I definitely agree it was pretty simple, but it would be more helpful if a suggestion/solution was provided so the OP knows how to fix the problem. Anyways, good eye catching that problem